# Mouseover/hover event for navigation bar link

Tags: html, css, hover, html-lists, onmouseover

I have a Navigation bar set up with images for the links to other pages of the website. I am trying to get a mouseover or hover effect for the links in the  list. Basically, I have a different image for each button that I want to appear when the user rolls the mouseover to click on the link. (If jquery or java is needed that is fine!) The HTML is:

```
<body>
 <div id="container"  style="images/logo.png">
 <p id="logo"><img class="project14"src="images/NavBar-01.png"></a></p>

    <ul id="nav">
        <li id=><a href="work.html"><img src="images/NavBar-02.png"></a></li>
        <li id=><a href="about.html"><img src="images/NavBar-03.png"></a></li>
        <li id=><a href="resume.html"><img src="images/NavBar-04.png"></a></li>
    </ul>
```

The CSS that I have is:

```
ul#nav {
    width: 956px; list-style: none; overflow: hidden; margin: -117px 0 60px 0;
}

ul#nav li {
    width: 145px; height: 109px; float: right;
    }
```

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a CSS-only tutorial that will get you on the right path:

http://css-tricks.com/css-menu-with-rollover-images/

EDIT in response to your comment "Can URL be used for an image that is in a folder on my desktop and not on the web?"

let's say that you have this folder structure:

```
/project
     /css
         your-css-file.css

     /images
         NavBar.png
```

your css can easily reference the `NavBar.png` image like this:

```
background-image: url('../images/NavBar.png');
```

basically, the `..` means "one level up from the current location", so from `/css` you would "be" in `/project` - then it would look into `/images` to find the image.

A proper folder structure is in fact a good starting point of any projects - the example above will work on both your local machine and your hosting. Absolute links (links that specify the full path e.g. `file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/your-user-name/Desktop/NavBar.png`) aren't the best approach as they are not flexible as relative urls - however the final answer to your question is "yes" you can link to an image that is on your desktop.

Comment: I got this to work but in my css it uses:                        background-image: URL('images/NavBar.png');  Can URL be used for an image that is in a folder on my desktop and not on the web?

Answer (score 0):

in jQuery:

```
$('#nav li').mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).find("img").attr("src","/path/to/new/image_hover.extension");
});

$('#nav li').mouseout(function() {
  $(this).find("img").attr("src","/path/to/old/image.extension");
});
```